# Is the documentation for gluProject missing perspective division?

Tags: c++, opengl, glu, projection-matrix

The OpenGL [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml) for `gluProject` writes that the projection of point `v` is computed using the given projection and model-view matrix via `v'' = P * M * v` then window coordinates are derived using the current viewport, e.g. `winZ = (v''(2) + 1)/2`.

Isn't this missing the perspective division of `v''` by `v''(3)` ? So then we should really have formulas like `winZ = (v''(2)/v''(3) + 1)/2`.

This agrees with my machine's opengl implementation and the implementation on the OpenGL [wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code).

So, is the documentation wrong?

Comment: I have a vague recollection of stumbling into this a few years back, but I can't find any references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the documentation appears to be missing the divide (which is the only reason for returning `GLU_FALSE`, by the way). Check the [mesa implementation](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/glu/tree/src/libutil/project.c) (lines 249-252), for instance.